# passing GCC flag -std=c++11 CXXFLAGS or CXX or CFLAGS

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, makefile

I really need some help with a basic question here please. I am about to give up forever on learning GCC as it seems like the basics just do not make sense to me. I have read hundreds of posts and can not figure out how to get a basic `-std=c++11` call to work passed via `configure`

In this example I have compiled gcc 5.3  and most programs compile ok, for example compiling httpd from source works no problems. But I keep getting errors relating to what I think is `-std=c++11`. All the posts I read say to pass `-std=c++11` and I have tried

```
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 
CXX=-std=c++11 
CFLAGS=-std=c++11
```

but the errors persist.

I am now attempting to compile aspell, and get the following error,

```
In file included from /home/mybin/include/algorithm:62:0,
                 from /home/atmp/aspell-0.60.6.1/common/string.hpp:13,
                 from /home/atmp/aspell-0.60.6.1/common/indiv_filter.hpp:12,
                 from /home/atmp/aspell-0.60.6.1/modules/filter/email.cpp:9:
/home/mybin/include/bits/stl_algo.h: In function ‘void std::random_shuffle(_RAIter, _RAIter)’:
/home/mybin/include/bits/stl_algo.h:4448:8: error: ‘rand’ is not a member of ‘std’
      + std::rand() % ((__i - __first) + 1);
```

`algorithm` seems to have installed correctly from the gcc5.3 compile. 
Please point me in the right direction to troubleshoot these types of errors.

Did I miss a compile option when compiling GCC?

Comment: You'd want to specify `CXXFLAGS` in the `Makefile`; the value will then be passed as a command-line option to `g++`. But since the `Makefile` is auto-generated by the `configure` script, your question is really about autotools, not about gcc.

Comment: I didn't know GCC compiled spells :)

Answer (score 1):

`std::rand` is defined in `<cstdlib>`, and it has nothing to do with C++11, this header was there a long time ago. Check that it is `#include`d in the source.

Comment: thanks for the pointer, I drew that conclusion due to a number of other posts suggesting that C++11 needed to be added a s aflag.i will check for that include. thanks Art

Comment: I have searched and still have no idea what to look for. `#included in the source.` what source do you refer? I have `cstdlib` in the main /include/ directory