# linux C++. Link shared objects and main

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, shared-libraries, gnu-make

I write simple testing program in C++, which will tell `Hello, Alex` and exit.
Here it's code:
`main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>


int main()
{
    void* descriptor = dlopen("dll.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    std::string (*fun)(const std::string name) = (std::string (*)(const std::string)) dlsym(descriptor, "sayHello");

    std::cout << fun("Alex") << std::endl;

    dlclose(descriptor);
    return 0;
}
```

`dll.h`:

```
#ifndef UNTITLED_DLL_H
#define UNTITLED_DLL_H

#include <string>    
std::string sayHello(const std::string name);
#endif
```

`dll.cpp`:

```
#include "dll.h"

std::string sayHello(const std::string name)
{
    return ("Hello, " + name);
}
```

`makefile`:

```
build_all : main dll.so

main : main.cpp
    $(CXX) -c main.cpp
    $(CXX) -o main main.o -ldl

dll.so : dll.h dll.cpp
    $(CXX) -c dll.cpp
    $(CXX) -shared -o dll dll.o
```

But when I build my code with make, I have such error:

> /usr/bin/ld: dll.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
>   dll.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   makefile:8: recipe for target 'dll.so' failed
>   make: *** [dll.so] Error 1

What did I make not correct?
P.S. I use `GNU Make 3.81` on `Ubuntu Server 14.04.3` with `GNU GCC 4.8.4`

**Update**
If I link `dll.so` file with -fPIC param, I have the same error

Comment: You must *compile* with `-fPIC`. *Linking* with `-fPIC` is meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, a bit off topic, but in your makefile, it would be better to specify build_all as a phony target

```
.PHONY: build_all
```

Next, you are compiling `dll.cpp` without relocatable code. You need to add `-fpic` or `-fPIC` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544035/what-is-the-difference-between-fpic-and-fpic-gcc-parameters) for an explanation of the difference).

```
$(CXX) -c dll.cpp -fpic
```

Lastly, unix doesn't automatically add file suffixes, so here you need to specify `.so`:

```
$(CXX) -shared -o dll.so dll.o
```