# Android OpenCV Linking CXX shared library fails

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I had a working Android Studio installation where I was programming an app with native C++ code and OpenCV. I stopped for kind of one year the development and resumed it a few days ago.

Since Android Studio was complaining that there were updates available I decided to update everything (Gradle, CMake, NDK...), and this was my error. Now the build stops at the linking phase:

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {--build C:\Users\Marco\AndroidStudioProjects\MyProject\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\x86_64 --target CppFilter}
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/CppFilter.dir/src/main/cpp/CppFilter.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library ..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\x86_64\libCppFilter.so
FAILED: cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe  --target=x86_64-none-linux-android21 --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/Marco/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/Marco/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-addrsig -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -stdlib=libc++ -O3 -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a -shared -Wl,-soname,libCppFilter.so -o ..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\x86_64\libCppFilter.so @CMakeFiles/CppFilter.rsp  && cd ."
D:/Downloads/opencv-3.3.1-android-sdk/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/libs/x86_64/libopencv_core.a(system.cpp.o):system.cpp:function cv::ipp::IPPInitSingleton::IPPInitSingleton(): error: undefined reference to 'std::cerr'

D:/Downloads/opencv-3.3.1-android-sdk/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/libs/x86_64/libopencv_core.a(system.cpp.o):system.cpp:function cv::ipp::IPPInitSingleton::IPPInitSingleton(): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)'

D:/Downloads/opencv-3.3.1-android-sdk/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/libs/x86_64/libopencv_core.a(system.cpp.o):system.cpp:function cv::ipp::IPPInitSingleton::IPPInitSingleton(): error: undefined reference to 'std::ostream::put(char)'

D:/Downloads/opencv-3.3.1-android-sdk/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/libs/x86_64/libopencv_core.a(system.cpp.o):system.cpp:function cv::ipp::IPPInitSingleton::IPPInitSingleton(): error: undefined reference to 'std::ostream::flush()'

... many more of the same type ...

clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I basically followed the default setup steps explained, for example:

- https://android.jlelse.eu/a-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-opencv-android-library-on-android-studio-19794e220f3c
- [Can OpenCV for Android leverage the standard C++ Support to get native build support on Android Studio 2.2 for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38958876/can-opencv-for-android-leverage-the-standard-c-support-to-get-native-build-sup)

Any ideas about what can be the cause of this error?

Actual version of Android Studio: 3.4, former: 2.something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it was due to the OpenCV version (3.3.1) being compiled in a way that was not compatible with newer versions of NDK or the Android SDK Build tools, check for example: [Why am I still getting undefined reference errors linking a static library with CMake in Android NDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52635674/why-am-i-still-getting-undefined-reference-errors-linking-a-static-library-with)

I downgraded NDK and Android SDK Build tools. Now it's working.