# Too many GOT entries for -fpic

Tags: c++, cmake, flags

I am using CMake to compile a C++ application (cross compilation).

The build directory seems to be successful but then when I build the config, I got the following error:

```
warning: too many GOT entries for -fpic, please recompile with -fPIC
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can someone explain what is the issue in that case?

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3544211/7691729) help?